# print value on netbeans log file

Tags: java

I tried with different ways to print value on Log File of Netbenas6.9.1 . I am using Tomcat6.0 . Also checked server log ..but values r not getting printed on any log.

Can any1 tell me how to print values using System.out.println() / java.util.Logger on console?

Comment: As I asked earlier , can you post your log4j conf file. and no need to create different account for it

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered that the code may not be actually getting executed? That might be why no log message appears.

Since you ask you can print the results of the `toString()` method of any object to the console like this:

`System.out.println( objectToBePrinted );`

You can also append to a file simply like this:

```
try {
PrintWriter logWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter( myLogFile, true ), true );
logWriter.println( objectToBePrinted );
logWriter.close();
} catch ( IOException ioe ) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
```

Before going down this route though it is worth considering using a debugger to investigate both why the logger is not logging and whatever issue you are trying to resolve through this logging. Debuggers give you access to a lot more information than a logger can.